One year of Programming Language Design and Implementation Stack Exchange!
Today marks one year since the start of the private beta at the beginning of this site. Happy birthday to langdev! Some vital statistics about the last year:

There have been a total of 2,434 answers posted to 877 questions.
Nearly 25,000 votes have been cast, and 1,358 different users have made at least one positive vote.
There are at least 1,572 users, 328 of whom have written a positive-scored answer, and 220 asked a well-received question.
The highest-reputation users is kaya3, with over 18.8k today.

The Yearling badge will start appearing in a few hours' time for users from the start of the private beta with at least 200 on-site reputation.
Our top-scoring (and top-viewed) question over that time is How should I read type system notation?, and the top-scoring answer is also by Alexis King to that question. Some other questions that drew a lot of eyes were

Why do programming languages use the asterisk * for multiplication?,
How can we compare expressive power between two Turing-complete languages?, and
Why do common Rust packages depend on C code?,

and more recently we've had questions like

How are "strong" and "weak" typing defined?,
Why don't popular regex engines support complement and intersection?,
Colored vs uncolored functions, and
Why do compilers typically convert code into abstract syntax/parse trees before the final product?
Why do (or don't) languages forbid unreachable code?

that have drawn a lot of interest and insight. The site has had attention from a number of notable persons in the field, both writing answers here and sharing and discussing them elsewhere. We can all thank everyone who's participated in making the site a useful resource, and a special note for Rydwolf Programs and lyxal who did a lot of work getting it off the ground in the first place.
Over the next year we can look forward to extending on what's here so far, and building up a useful library for professional, academic, and hobbyist programming-language creators, and anyone with an interest in the whys, hows, and whats of language designs and implementations.
For right now, there are some high-scoring questions still waiting for an answer as well, including What is the relationship between STG and RVSDG?, What impact do type sigils have on programmers?, Why were OS/360 PL/I procedure calls so expensive?, and What styles of interpreter are not well-supported by RPython? — maybe you know the answer to those!
The anniversary of the public beta will be next month, 27 June, when there'll be a whole lot more Yearling badges awarded.
Thanks to everyone who's contributed to the site over the last year!

Been a year already? Man. Time flies. Feels like yesterday I joined this site.

Didn't learn different descriptions so almost useless to me...

Hooray!
This has been a massive ride, from the start of the proposal in Area 51 to launching into public beta. I'd like to say 'thank you' to every single user who contributed to this site, but also especially to lyxal, Michael and Alexis, who work hard removing spam accounts (also lyxal, for completely nuking them).
Also props to the folks who came from over at CGCC to start the site, particularly Rydwolf (your site is now old, congratulations). I think a big part of why people stuck around would be everyone being welcoming so congrats everyone on that too.
I'd also like to thank the Community Managers who helped the site through the early stages when we didn't have pro-tem mods.
Now, if you'll excuse me, I'm going to go make a cake!
